# What is the best free (or under 200 dollar) database manager software?

Tags: mysql, database, database-management

I am currently using Toad, but am not very satisied.

Comment: "The best" -> subjective. At the very least, provide a few criteria by which the available options should be judged.

Comment: [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com) hands down. This is a dupli-tetra-quadruplicate though

Comment: How long have you been using toad?  Which version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dbvisualiser http://www.dbvis.com/

Answer (score 2):

[SQuirreL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Have used Squirrel for years and it suits my daily work. Still am numbed why the editor font size cannot be changed.